# Почему в неприятности втравливают?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Тут уже как-то обсуждалось слово "травить", но мне оно интересно в другом значении: "втравливать" — то есть, впутывать во что-то. Почему именно втравливать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересно происхождение слова ТРАВИТЬ - это тратить (кстати, трава - это то, что тратят, употребляют в пищу). Поэтому современное "травить" - это уничтожать, а втравливать -  вовлекать кого-то в деятельное участие в этом процессе, в частности в ловлю дичи. Также известно переносное значение слова: травить - это изводить себя печальными воспоминаниями или мучить другого нападками, преследованием.

Слово "втравливать" также может употребляться в переносном смысле - это ВОВЛЕКАТЬ других во что-то дурное, несущее неприятные последствия. Поэтому мы говорим:Мне нужно было обоих их втравить в игру.Не люблю когда меня втравливают в чужие дела, чужие отношения.Не надо втравливать страны  в междоусобицу.

Answer (score 1):

У слова травить есть значение (спец. охотничье) травить — преследовать жертву сворой.

От него - втравить - приучить к травле  (спец.). Втравить собаку - ввести её в процесс травли. Отсюда переносное знач. "вовлечь, втянуть в какое-н. нежелательное, неприятное дело" (прост.). Втравить в преступное дело - ввести в процесс преступного дела.